# Why does my spellcheck disallow themself, but not themselves?

Tags: orthography

When I type "themself" my computer browser spellchecker underlines it in red. It's an error.

When I right click the word I'm offered 3 alternatives "them self", "them-self", and "themselves".

Why is "themselves" correct but "themself" wrong?

Comment: All it means is that your browser has decided to fall on one side of the fence rather than the other.

Comment: 'When I type "themself" my computer browser spellchecker underlines it in red.' does not necessarily mean  'It's an error.'